# What to read to learn probability and stochastics for engineering?

Tags: probability

I have this course in this term and the reference book is Papoulis book. But I prefer a newer book with similar subjects so that I can both learn and be ready for the exam. Is there a book similar so that I can learn these lessons ? I am in 3rd semester of software engineering.
(I do not want a more complicated or advanced book)

Comment: When I read the title, the first thing I was going to recommend is Papoulis.  It is what I use when I need a reference.

Comment: @Joel is it freely available on the internet?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not.  It is a standard reference for engineering and stochastics.  It has a good treatment that is approachable by someone with an elementary analysis background.